# 502 Bad gateway in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, delayed-job, http-status-code-502

I'm using rails server I upgraded ruby to 2.7 and rails to 6.0.3.6, delayed_job_active_record to 4.1.6, when api requests our server sometimes our app responses with 502 bad gateway, is this because of mismatch in versions?

Comment: Usually, 502 Bad gateway means the app is killed or not responding. Can you put more context behind this error? I am assuming the app is behind a load balancer, proxy? If possible for you to get a log of the app itself from the server?  Can you run the app in your local with same versions of the gem?

Comment: @NiteshPurohit I'm able to run this in my local, we do have load balancer and autoscaling also.We are using this app to send select and send mails via sendgrid. When our app is continously called it results in 502 error, after 5-6 seconds the server will be back and app works as expected

Comment: Looks like the app is getting killed, and comes back up. I will suggest looking at logs exactly why the app is killed. You can also monitor if you need more instances to support the traffic. But definitely, any kind of log which says why the app is killed will help. If you are using AWS as your provider then, try to look into cloudwatch to see if you can get any logs for the instance or app.

Comment: Were you able to fix it? How?